# SQL query how to compare string

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables:

Customers:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Surname
4. City

Orders:

1. OrderId
2. CustomerId
3. Purchase
4. Price

I'm trying to find customer id,name,surname where he hasn't Purchase "Pizza".
Any help to fix my query? I tried with cp.Purchase != "Pizza" but doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,FirstName,LastName
FROM Customers c 
INNER JOIN Orders cp ON c.ID = cp.OrderID 
ORDER BY c.ID
WHERE cp.Purchase LIKE '%Pizza%'
```

Comment: Should join be CustomerID with ID?  WHERE  should be after the selected columns not in the end

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: The immediate answer to your question is `purchase <> 'Pizza'`. But this is really fundamental stuff, I'd suggest taking basic classes, going through tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select * from Customers  where Id not in (
  select CustomerId From Orders WHERE cp.Purchase LIKE '%Pizza%'
)
```

Comment: Yep, such lookups should be written with `IN` or `EXISTS`, not with joins. I prefer your solution with `IN` over the alternative with `EXISTS` here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The right query is

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.ID, c.Name, c.Surname
FROM Customers c JOIN Orders o on c.ID = o.CustomerID
WHERE c.ID <> ALL (
SELECT c2.ID
FROM Customers c2 JOIN Orders o2 on c.ID = o2.CustomerID
WHERE o2.Purchase = 'Pizza')
```

This is because you are looking for who never bought a pizza, so you will select data of customers which ID never appear (<> ALL) in orders table in a record where a pizza was bought.

By the way, check also SQL base, try understand before getting the answer.

Comment: No, this is not the solution. You are retrieving all customers who had at least one non-pizza order. OP is looking for all customers who never had a pizza order.

Comment: My fault, I didn't red correctly, I fixed it, thanks